# Add text from 2 listBox to one listBox

Tags: c#, .net

How can I add items from 2 listBox to one listBox?

ex: listBox1 contain Hello listBox2 contain World! So if button1 is clicked in listbox3 will display Hello World! side bye side but not in a new line like

Hello

World!

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  listBox3.Items.Add(listBox1.Items + listBox2.Items);
}
```

Comment: How many `Items` have your `listBox1` and `listBox2` ?

Comment: Depends on the list it does not contain a specific number.

Comment: So, do you wanna add the same indexed items properly? Like `listBox1.Items[0] + listBox2.Items[0]`, `listBox1.Items[1] + listBox2.Items[1]` and so on...?

Comment: I want to make it like this ex:listbox1 contain 3 words and listbox2 have 1 words so the output will be each words on listbox1 will combined with listbox2.

Comment: In your case, do you want totally 4 words in your `listBox3` or just 2 words (first word of `listbox1` + first word of `listbox2`) ?

Comment: all words in listBox1 will be + with listBox2 in listBox3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  listBox3.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", listBox1.Items[0].ToString().Trim() , listBox2.Items[0].ToString().Trim()));
}
```

if you need all words in two list box to a one list box

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  listBox3.Items.Add( string.Format("{0} {1}", string.Join(" ", listBox1.Items.Cast<string>()) , string.Join(" ", listBox2.Items.Cast<string>())));
}
```

**Update :**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  listBox3.Items.AddRange(listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Zip(listBox2.Items.Cast<string>(), (first, second) => first + " " + second).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Inside string you have 2 placeholders but you provide only one concatenated string. This would print out `(listBox1 value + listBox2 value) {1}`.

Comment: @terrala7 append `ToString()` after `Items[]` and before `Trim()`.

Comment: this works but how to do this with multiple words from the first listBox :)

Comment: it works but if my listBox1 contain Hello Hi Sup and my listBox2 contain World! how can i make the output in listBox3 will become Hello World! Hi World! Sup World!instead of Hello Hi Sup World!

Comment: Thanks but not working it only display System.Linq.Enumerable+<Zipltelator>d__7a`3[System.String.System.String.System.String] in the listBox3

Comment: Thanks but still not working too :( it only display the first word from the listBox1, the output is only Hello World!, missing the Hi World! and Sup World! :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you said;

> all words in listBox1 will be + with listBox2 in listBox3

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string s = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
  {
      s += listBox1.Items[i].ToString() + " ";
  }

  for(int j = 0; j < listBox2.Items.Count; j++)
  {
      s += listBox2.Items[j].ToString() + " ";
  }

  listBox3.Items.Add(s.Trim());
}
```

> but ex:my listBox1 contain Hello Hi Sup and my listBox2 contain World!
>   after click in listBox3 it will become Hello Hi Sup World! instead of
>   Hello World! Hi World! Sup World!

If you want as a one item in your `listBox3`, you can use upper solution. If you want as total 4 item in your `listBox3`, you can use it like;

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  for(int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
  {
      listBox3.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
  }

  for(int j = 0; j < listBox2.Items.Count; j++)
  {
      listBox3.Items.Add(listBox2.Items[j].ToString());
  }

}
```

Comment: not working this will only add lists from listBox1 to listBox3

Comment: @terrala7 No. This will adds all members of listBox1 and listBox2 to listBox3 as a one item.

Comment: ops it works but ex:my listBox1 contain Hello Hi Sup and my listBox2 contain World! after click in listBox3 it will become Hello Hi Sup World! instead of Hello World! Hi World! Sup World!

Comment: thanks but i think you typo at the listBox number it should be listBox3.Items.Add(listBox2.Items[j].ToString()); instead of listBox3.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[j].ToString()); but still it does not does what i wanted to do :)